# Fast way to create a binary list C of len(A) given two lists A and B

Tags: python, list, performance

I have two lists `A` and `B` that are ***large*** (`len(A)` is around 200K and `len(B)` is around 20K). I want to generate a new list `C` of length `len(A)` which has 1 at all positions `i` where `A[i]` is in `B`, and 0 otherwise. What is the most computationally-efficient way of doing this in Python? In other words, is there a more efficient way than below?

```
C = []
for x in A:
    if x in B:
        C.append(1)
    else:
        C.append(0)
```

Comment: Yes, make `B` a `set`. Otherwise, this algorithm is `O(M*N)` whereas if you do `B = set(B)` first, you get `O(N)`

Comment: Are any of the list elements duplicate values?

Comment: @MichaelRuth No

Comment: @juanapa.arrivillaga Ahh, just make B a set, doesn't matter then.

Comment: @MichaelRuth why would it matter if there were duplicates?

Comment: What's "very large?"

Comment: @MichaelRuth `len(A)` is around 200K and `len(B)` is around 20K. Edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For performance, you should make `B` a `set` object. `set` have constant-time membership testing. This will improve the efficiency of your overall algorithm from polynomial time O(N*M) to linear time, O(N):

```
c = []
B = set(B)
for x in A:
    if x in B:
        C.append(1)
    else:
        C.append(0)
```

Comment: Nice solution, only caveat is that `B` gets changed to be a `set`, destroying the ordering and dropping possible duplicate elements (which are not an issue for the concrete problem, as I read in the comments above, but might be for a general solution). If `B` is intended to be still used as the original `list` further down below, you should use a new name for the `set(B)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension but keep in mind that it doesn't provide a big improvement in terms of efficiency over the loop approach:

```
[1 if x in B else 0 for x in A]
```

---

Update: The fastest approach would be to prepare a map from B and use that for searching.

```
B_map = {elt: True for elt in B}
C = [1 if B_map.get(x, False) else 0 for x in A]
```

Comment: I think it should be `[1 if x in B else 0 for x in A]`

Comment: yes, you are right, I misread the question.

Comment: This is not a more computationally efficient approach, it is *exactly* equivalent.

Comment: The issue here is the search, it's O(n) for each element where len(A) = m and len(B) = n. If you search a list, first sort it and use the bisect module for binary search. The module provides a way to do this while preserving the original indices of the lists.

Comment: The fastest way would be probably to prepare a dictionary object with `B` and use that. I have updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

**tldr;** Turn `B` into a `set` and use a list comprehension. @Krishna Chaurasia's comprehension with `set(B)` is the fastest solution presented.

---

You should definitely use `set(B)` for the search, as others have suggested. This improves performance for large `B`.

Now to improve performance for large `A`, and therefore `C`. Preallocate `C`. Note that preallocation is only helpful in the case that it replaces an `append()`, it does not speed up comprehensions.

```py
from timeit import timeit

setup = '''
A = list(range(1000000))
B = set(range(500000, 1500000))
'''

stmt_for_no_preallocation = '''
C = []
for x in A:
    if x in B:
        C.append(1)
    else:
        C.append(0)
'''

stmt_for_preallocation = '''
C = [0] * len(A)
for i, x in enumerate(A):
    if x in B:
        C[i] = 1
'''

stmt_comp = 'C = [1 if x in B else 0 for x in A]'

stmt_comp_map = '''
B_map = {elt: True for elt in B}
C = [1 if B_map.get(x, False) else 0 for x in A]
'''

stmt_comp_map_alias_get = '''
B_map = {elt: True for elt in B}
get = B_map.get
C = [1 if get(x, False) else 0 for x in A]
'''

n = 10
print('for without preallocating C')
print(timeit(stmt_for_no_preallocation, setup=setup, number=n))
print('for with preallocating C')
print(timeit(stmt_for_preallocation, setup=setup, number=n))
print('list comprehension')
print(timeit(stmt_comp, setup=setup, number=n))
print('list comprehension with map')
print(timeit(stmt_comp_map, setup=setup, number=n))
print('list comprehension with map and alias B_map.get to local scope')
print(timeit(stmt_comp_map_alias_get, setup=setup, number=n))
```

Output:

```
for without preallocating C
0.900570491
for with preallocating C
0.723135233
list comprehension
0.51548745
list comprehension with map
1.5568766299999997
list comprehension with map and alias B_map.get to local scope
1.3334449179999996
```