# Improve Runtime to reduce list 1 to only contain entries that match to list 2 in python

Tags: python, performance

I am working with sequencing data and need to count the number of reads that match to a grna library in python. Simplified my data looks like this:

```
reads = ['abc', 'abc','def', 'ghi']
grnas = ['abc', 'ghi']
```

The grnas list is unique, while the reads list can contain entries that are not of interest and don't match to the grnas or are repeat entries. What I want to do is to reduce the list of reads to only contain those entries which match to one entry in grnas.

I am currently doing this with a list comprehension like this:

```
reads_matched = [read for read in reads if (read in grnas)]
```

in my example for reads_matched this would return :

```
['abc', 'abc', 'ghi']
```

Since both of my lists are very large (6 million entries in reads and 80k entries in grnas) this of course takes some time to compute. Is there any way for me to speed this up further?

I have tried writing it as a for loop or while loop in many different variations but this is much slower than the method I listed above. In general I am very inexperienced with runtime improvements and have come to this solution through trial and error so any tips to further improve would be appreciated!

Comment: convert `grnas` to `set` which will help make lookup faster.

Comment: I am not sure whether it will speed it up but you can try `set(reads).intersection(grnas)`

Comment: If it does not work I would slice `reads ` into multiple lists and use parallel processing to get the match

Comment: Maybe try `divide and conquer` approach? But this will increase the number of variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast way to create a binary list C of len(A) given two lists A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434635/fast-way-to-create-a-binary-list-c-of-lena-given-two-lists-a-and-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case cannot be less of O(n).
Using single process the best solution is:

```
[x for x in reads if x in set(grnas)]
or
[x for x in reads if x in dict.fromkeys(grnas)]
```

but this is a simple case to parallelyze, you can reduce input data in some bunch of works and append all results.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks! I do want to parallelize it but want to make sure the actual code its running is as efficient as possible before I do. Changing the grnas list to a set gave me about a 100X increase in speed (at least on the test examples I ran and timed).

Answer (score 0):

as the worst case of complexity search in both `set` & `dict` in python is some how `O(N)` so the complexity of the program would be `O(N * M)`. it would not be efficient to use them. so use the `Counter` object which will do the search in `O(1)` so the whole program would be done in
`O(max(N, M))` complexity.

```py
from collections import Counter

reads = ['abc', 'abc','def', 'ghi']
grnas = ['abc', 'ghi']

count = Counter(reads)
for g in grnas:
  print(g, count[g])
```